# ¿Cómo insertar código en las entradas de Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugin

En algunos blogs de programación he visto algo como esto en las entradas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría poder hacer lo mismo. Sin embargo, no solo quiero que sea visible el código, también me gustaría ejecutarlo en ese momento. Algo como cuando ponemos los snippets aquí y aparece el código de Javascript, CSS, HTML y podemos ejecutarlo.

¿Cómo puedo hacer eso? ¿Con algún plugin? ¿O qué página me brinda ese servicio?

Answer (score 2):

Es un plugin para WP, [crayon](https://es-mx.wordpress.org/plugins/crayon-syntax-highlighter/)

CHECATE ESTE ENLACE

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar un fiddle embebido en tu página o entrada. No requiere plugin.

Primero hay que crear el fiddle con el código correspondiente, guardarlo y finalmente ir a la opción "Embed" en la parte superior y copiar el código que debes incrustar en tu página. Es algo similar a colocar un mapa de google maps en tu página.

https://jsfiddle.net/